# Storing set of commands output to a shell variable throws error

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, command-line

In My shell script, I have following lines...

```
name=`grep -i "client" fin${i}.txt`
jobplan_name=`${name} | cut -d "=" -f4 | cut -d " " -f1`
echo ${jobplan_name}
```

**Output:**

```
<JOBP:  not found
```

Please correct me where the problem is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need an `echo`:

```
jobplan_name=`echo ${name} | cut -d "=" -f4 | cut -d " " -f1`
```

Comment: Without the `echo`, you are trying to execute a command named by `name` and piping its output to `cut`, rather than piping the value of `name` itself to `cut`.

Comment: Because the backticks say *"give me the output of the command contained within"*. The contents of the `name` variable is **not** a command recognized by your system: Hence "not found". The output of the `echo` command is what you want: the string that the `name` variable contains.